# Large synchronous buck stage after PFC circuit

Tags: power-supply, motor, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-motor, buck

I am working on a fairly small motor controller (2kW).  The power input is AC 110-220VAC, so there is a PFC stage that boosts the initial DC voltage to 390VDC.  After this stage, I require a 160-165VDC stage for brushless DC motor commutation.  PFC and commutation are not a problem.

I have been looking at manufacturers online and they seem to be low on high output voltage controllers (input range as well..)

What is a viable and efficient buck stage for this circuit?

My current thought process is down a path of using a lower voltage, synchronous buck, controller chip and isolating the chip from the input/output via a low power DC supply and external gate drivers.  That all seems very complicated...

What ideas do you have stack??

Comment: I would think you would want some isolation in the power supply somewhere, that usually happens after the PFC.  I would look at something like a phase-shifted full bridge for 2KW at 165VDC.

Comment: 2 kW PWM voltage regulation is not a walk in the park no matter what topology you choose. We need you to be braver and think about what MOSFETs you might use and what sort of switching frequency and efficiency you think you need.

Comment: Does the motor controller require such a stable voltage? If the motor insulation can handle it, 50%PWM at 300V is not different from 100%PWM at 150V. So... Do you need the buck? After all, you got MOSFETs and a big inductor that happens to be a motor, that's all you need to make a buck converter...

Comment: I'm amused by the fact that you call a 2kW controller "fairly small". What do you consider to be a "normal size"? :-)

Comment: @JohnD - No isolation necessary on this one. I'll save the 3%.

Comment: @Andyaka - For the output LC and TO package this is viable if mounted to a plate around 50-120kHz. N-CH GET of course!

Comment: @peufeu - Motor is rated to 180VDC and I do not want to exceed.

Comment: @DaveTweed - I would put 30-50k around limits where larger bus bars and packages are needed.  Also ignore the silly repost below, I'll delete it when I'm on my computer.

Comment: What is your spec for speed vs power control and efficiency? Is it open loop? Will there be surge current limits?

Comment: The duty cycle on the commutation stage is limited at 85%. There is PID/PI control on the motor via velocity loop. Surge will be caught by a rate limiter or comparator short circuit control.